# iTextPDF C# Generating print quality pdf Magazines dynamically

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, itext

iText C# Generating print quality pdf Magazines dynamically.

I’m currently evaluating iText for our upcoming project.

Briefly requirement is as follows.

We have list of articles which we need to write to PDF in order of priority for the users. As many as we can fit in 8 pages.

We have 4 Sheets (A3), each sheet contains 2 Pages (A4).

Sequence of pages will be:

Sheet 1 – Contains Magazine front and back cover

Sheet 2 – Contains Page 2 | Page 7

Sheet 3 – Contains Page 6 | Page 3

Sheet 4 – Contains Page 4 | Page 5

Sheets will also contain bleed area and will be sent directly to the printers.
As you can see that follow of the articles need to be from Sheet 2 / Page 2 to Sheet 3 / Page 3 and so on.

Also magazine needs to look very nice so will need to use branding colour, different fonts and images and also need to have layouts 3-columns or 2 columns to sections with columns etc.

Also need to aware of how much text will fit in have to avoid orphan headings if there isn’t at least one line of normal text under it.

Is this something achievable, anyone built anything like that using iText with C# before?

How can we control flow of text on pages?
How can we create different layouts for text and image in columns and blocks?

Thank you.

Comment: The short answer is "Yes" (as indicated by @FernandoGonzalezSanchez). The long answer is too long in the context of Stack Overflow. Your question is too broad. Make sure that you also take a look at the [official documentation](http://developers.itextpdf.com/), see for instance the [iText 7: Building Blocks](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks) tutorial.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie thank you for your reply , I understand and appreciate your comments, I looked at New York Times example in chapter 3 of iText 7, its pretty cool what it does. the method 

public static void AddArticle(Document doc, String title, String author, iText.Layout.Element.Image img, String text) is adding all the articles , how can I stop orphan headings and push them to next column using this example / method

Comment: I found , element Div and setKeepTogether method to keep things together, which is GREAT! but is there a way to Simulate to see what will fit and what won't because, I need to loop into my list of available articles and see if some articles are short enough to fit in, let say I have half column available, I would then like to calculate that if any article will fit into that half column, with or without image, so I can fill the magazine space better instead of leaving it empty while there are still articles which could have fit in that space easily

Answer (score 1):

PDF is already print quality, you just need to care of the PDF layout. For the layouts, you can check these samples

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/89/itextsharp-page-layout-with-columns

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/87/iTextSharp-Working-with-images

Comment: While those links may indeed be helpful, stackoverflow answers are expected to be self-contained; at least one should show the pivotal ideas in the answer itself instead of merely off-site.

Answer (score 1):

I would advice taking a look at iText7, since it handles layouting and multiple columns better than iText5 (which is what the examples Fernando are written with).

The official documentation is found at http://developers.itextpdf.com/,
a starters guide to iText7 can be found in [this tutorial](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-net), which includes a multi-column example in chapter 3.

EDIT: Pointers on defining your own renderers can be found in [Chapter 2 of Building Blocks](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-2-working-rootelement) (Examples are only available in java for the moment). There's a bit about adding in area breaks before titles and defining your own columnrenderer

Comment: Thank you very much , I have checked this example in chapter 3, New York Times, is there a way to control the flow of the articles ? i.e some articles will be longer than others, so we have to see how many can fit in a column , also we need to avoid having orphan article headings / titles on their own as a last line in a column, article heading should at least have one line of text otherwise it should be pushed to next column if we have any. Also the number of the pages will always be 6 in total so we must stop after we have rendered 6 pages

Comment: I found , element Div and setKeepTogether method to keep things together, which is GREAT! but is there a way to Simulate to see what will fit and what won't because, I need to loop into my list of available articles and see if some articles are short enough to fit in, let say I have half column available, I would then like to calculate that if any article will fit into that half column, with or without image, so I can fill the magazine space better instead of leaving it empty while there are still articles which could have fit in that space easily –

Comment: It's definitely do-able, but we don't have an example for your specific use-case lying around (I'm an iText employee btw). I'd say, maybe take a look at defining your own custom renderers by extending columnrenderer. I'll see if I can dig up something more when I got some spare time.

Comment: Thank you mate! just investigating if I should go with iText5 or 7 use low-level objects for high-level since I need to have a control and calculate how much text I can fit in and use images and text so it is a composite mode not text mode since Pdf needs to be fancy

Comment: Hi - did you manage to find something? really needed help with this one , kindly if you can please point me to right direction please and share some example or sample code with me please? of course when you have time , I'll be waiting thank you , I understand that I'll have to extend ColumnRenderer but how do I check how much space is left and see if any article in the list will fit in with or without image. waiting , thank you

Comment: Did not find any ready made examples, but I do have a few ideas that might help (using the OnPageEnd event) and I need to check some of the renderer code first to see if it is possible to extract remaining area. I'll see if I can find some time to do a proper write-up today.

Comment: And I didn't look all that well yesterday, added some more links to the answer.